# What nationality is Steve Trevor?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, wonder-woman-2017

In the *Wonder Woman* film, Captain Steve Trevor mentions repeatedly that he is working for British Intelligence, and his main goal is to get back to London to speak with his commanders.

But while all of Trevor's allies and his secretary speak with a clearly British accent, Trevor's accent is American.

### What nationality is Trevor, or why is his accent so different from his allies?

Comment: I think I'd be very amused if Chris Pine tried to pull a foreign accent, a la Brad Pitt's character and his Italian in _Inglourious Basterds_.

Comment: When in the lasso of truth, he said he's American, but working for the British. The Native American points to him when Diana asks who defeated his people. I can't find a copy of the script otherwise I'd post an answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

During the scene with the amazons in which Steve is wrapped in the lasso of truth he states that he's an American assigned to work with British intelligence as a spy. The Native American "chief" also confirms this later when Diana asks the chief about his homeland and who took it away from him, and he nods towards Steve and says his people.

Comment: I'm not sure Chief's reply adds anything. He could be referring to white people on general.

Comment: At the end, we also see 50 stars on Steve's Belt and I believe an American Flag on his lapel.

Comment: As I've mentioned below, it's a nitpick but he doesn't say he's an American. He says he's part of the US expeditionary forces.

Comment: @Edlothiad Shouldn't there only be 48 stars during WWI?

Comment: @eshier I didn't count, I don't know how many there are, there's a bunch of stars

Comment: Also in his picture on the wall of at end we see a "Yankee" style hat painted on his plane.

Answer (score 6):

The film isn't much help. All we're told is that he's

> *Captain Steve Trevor… Pilot… American Expeditionary Force.*

and that he's working on secondment for British Intelligence. This doesn't actually confirm his *nationality,* merely who he's working for.

---

Luckily, the omniscient narrator in the film's novelisation is kind enough to give us proof of his background.

> *While Diana watched, the others helped themselves to guns. It pleased
> her that she could recognize them too. Sammy grabbed a Lee–Enfield
> Mark VII, .303 caliber. And **Steve, the American,** picked up an American
> gun, a Winchester 12-gauge repeating shotgun. Thanks to Steve, she
> also knew their magazine capacities and effective firing ranges.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Wonder Woman: Official Movie Novelisation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1785653784)</sup></sub>

Comment: Doesn't "American Expeditionary Force." give it away and Mi5 and MI6 did work with the American government agencies so its not unlikely he is working for Mi6 or MI5

Comment: @Neuromancer - The AEF were an American unit, but they weren't staffed *exclusively* by Americans, nor is there any special reason to disprove the (admittedly unlikely) theory that Steve isn't a Canadian whose parents moved to the US when he was young, hence the accent.